# WordPress - how to get posts's parent page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set all my posts to a page called Work under Settings -> Reading.

And that I assume that now Work is the parent page of the posts.

So now I am trying to get the posts' parent which is Work using this code,

```
print_r(get_permalink($post->post_parent));
```

But why can't I view the data of this parent page?  I get the current page's data instead.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

single.php

```
<!-- container -->
<div class="container">

<?php
// Include the page nav.
get_template_part( 'nav-page', 'nav' );
?>

<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    /*
     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
     */
    get_template_part( 'content-single', get_post_format() );

// End the loop.
endwhile;
?>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

content-single.php

```
<?php global $post;?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        ///
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
        var_dump($post->post_parent->ID);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have declared the global $post; ? Put all your code pls

Comment: yes I have. please see my edit above/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have assigned a posts page, this is not a parent. Instead you must call:

```
$blog_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
get_permalink($blog_id);
```

Comment: tried that but the result is `NULL`. Yes I am in the wp loop.

Comment: My bad I just tested myself! I revised the answer! Are you inside the loop?

Comment: i might be missing something. with `var_dump(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID ));` I get `int(0)`.

Comment: I see, have you declared global $post; in content-single.php ?

Comment: I might have missed that. where in content-single.php to put `global $post;`?

Comment: `$pID = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );` is not going to help because $post_ID is not declared. That is why you are getting int(0)

Comment: Yes true, in case you have done this, use: $post->ID

Comment: I have out the global $post at the top (see my edit), and with `var_dump(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ));` I still get `0`

Comment: thanks for the latest edit. yes have tried that but still the same.

Comment: note that I am looking for posts' parent. not the children pages' parent.

Comment: Right of course, you set the post page called 'Work'. and you wish to get the Posts page. Technically this is not a parent so I have been looking at this from the wrong angle! Perhaps [this might help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/how-to-find-the-posts-page-home-page-programatically) or try **$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );**

Comment: yes. I think this is the answer `$blog_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );`. what is `global $post;` for actually?

Comment: Great, I'll amend the answer. Regarding to global $post: Wordpress sets variables ($post) globally so you can access them from any file. To load them call on the **global** function. I believe function the_post() form the loop does a similar thing so you can use $post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Work is not the parent page. You are setting the page Work to be the main page for the blog. The reason you are getting a 0 when you try to get the parent post ID is because there is not an actual parent of the Work page, as setting a page to the default reading page does not make it a parent page.

If you were to create a page About and then set Work to be a child of that, you could use `$parentID = $post->post_parent` within the loop to retrieve the ID for the About page.

Comment: I have tried `$parentID = $post->post_parent` and I am still getting `0`.

Comment: Right, because Work has no parent. Setting it to the default page under Settings -> Reading does not make it a child of any other page, which is why you are getting that result.

Comment: `Work` is the parent of posts.

Comment: Out of the box, blog posts themselves do not have parent pages. A page can have a parent, but a post cannot. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36300/can-posts-have-parents